# Register class with IServiceCollection after startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

In my application I have a bunch of services I want to register after the startup.

LateClass :

```
public LateClass(IServiceCollection col)
{
    col.AddTransient<IEventHandler, JsonPackageUpdated>();
}
```

And register the LateClass itself of course:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     col.AddTransient<LateClass>();
 }
```

But the IServiceCollection will break my application and I got an exception that I can't resolve it.

Comment: To do this you need to add the IServiceCollection to the container: `services.AddTransient<IServiceCollection>(services)`. I would strongly advise against it, but I guess you have your reasons.

Comment: Well my reason is, that I want to change an IOptions data based on an event I got...so event got fired -> Change the iOption with the service.configure<Options>() method -> Make it available everywhere with DI - what du you think about that usecase?

Comment: And I got an error after implementing your solution:"Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' for service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection'."

Comment: IOptions are not designed for changing, you need to create a service that would have access to event and inject it to every dependent service

Comment: Its not about a service, its about the data I got from the event. So Event comes, brings a payload -> The payload is needed in 10 classes. How to bring it there without using arguments in methods?

Comment: through dependency injection. you would only need to do configurationService.GetSetting(event) or something like that. so you dont need to modify your method signature

Comment: Try using AddSingleton instead

Comment: @YegorAndrosov Thanks for your answer! I can't follow you, I need the data itself, can you show me how to register data in the DI container? I need a DataModel right? And then?

Comment: Since IOptions are registered as singletons you can update properties of the value (property) and see the change reflected elsewhere. But that assumes no IOptionsSnapsot (and perhaps no named options) and also that the services using the options are re-reading their values and not caching them or using them during construction and discarding them

Comment: Application build dependency object graph at startup, so you would not be able to register or re-register things afterwards. For web applications such graph built when request come in as well. You need provide data from one class to another without them knowing about each other - quick and dirty approach register singleton class and update it every time new event is raised, then when another class will consume "shared" instance it will get updated values. - This is very dirty approach which can not be used if events can be processed in parallel.

Comment: Consider to pass some identifier to all methods, then those methods can retrieve required data based on that identifier.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems like a XY problem. You have a problem which you decided to solve with Dependency Injection and IOptions type - and you are asking why this is not working. But actual issue is different, can you describe actual problem you have, we would be glad to help. For example, what is the relation between event and their processor, Can all methods be executed at once or there some specified order, does methods rely only on event data or they need data result from other methods?

Comment: could you add the exception , to your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering OP's question in comments how dynamic configuration should be handled.

You can make your ConfigurationService as much compex as you want (inject other services that have something else injected) until it has circular dependency.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new ServiceCollection();

            collection.AddTransient<ConfigurationService>();
            collection.AddTransient<EventProcessService>();


            var serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

            var eventService = serviceProvider.GetService<EventProcessService>();

            eventService.ProcessEvent(0);
        }
    }

    public class ConfigurationService
    {
        public ConfigurationService(
                // you could use whatever configuration provider you have: db context for example
            )
        {
        }

        public string GetSettingBasedOnEventType(int eventType)
        {
            switch (eventType)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Some setting value";
                case 1:
                    return "Some other setting value";
                default:
                    return "Not found";
            }
        }
    }

    public class EventProcessService
    {
        private readonly ConfigurationService configurationService;

        public EventProcessService(ConfigurationService configurationService)
        {
            this.configurationService = configurationService;
        }

        public void ProcessEvent(int eventType)
        {
            var settingForEvent = configurationService.GetSettingBasedOnEventType(eventType);

            // process event with your setting
        }
    }
}
```